# Accessing this.state value to other Class [React Native]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I just wanna ask how can i access this.state.sampleString from other class.. Here's my code

```
class MainClass extends Component {

  constructor(props){
      super(props)


      this.state = {
        sampleString: 'Test String'
      }

      this.getValue = this.getValue.bind(this);
    }


    getValue(){
        //console.log(this.state.sampleString);
        return this.state.sampleString
    }

}
```

=========

This is my function from My second class to get the value of "this.state. sampleString" from MainClass

```
function getValueFromMainClass() {

  var stringFromClassHeader = () => {HeaderWithBg.getValue()}

  console.log(stringFromClassHeader.sampleString);

}
```

Why it returns "undefined"?

Thanks alot. Im a new in react native.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can send the `this.state.sampleString` as a prop to other components and use it there. A simple example of this is like below:

```
class MainClass extends Component {
  constructor(props){
      super(props)
      this.state = {
        sampleString: 'Test String'
      }

      this.getValue = this.getValue.bind(this);
    }

    getValue(){
        //console.log(this.state.sampleString);
        return this.state.sampleString
    }

    render(){
        return (
        <ChildClass sampleString={this.state.sampleString}/>


          )
        }
    }

class ChildClass extends Component {
    somefunction() {
        //console.log(this.props.sampleString);
        return this.props.sampleString
    }

    render(){
        return ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give me a sample code? Im new to react native.. Thanks alot sir!

Comment: Thank you Sir!! :)

Comment: Happy to help you. :)