# How can i show ActivityIndicator popup with backdrop

Tags: react-native, android-activity, components, loading

Api Handler and hitapi is my method I Want to show loading when i call hitapi method so please suggest me how can i create popup for ActivityIndicator with backdrop

```
class ApiHandler {


  hitapi(url,data,method) {

  }

}

const api = new ApiHandler();
export default api;
```

Loading component:

```
 <View style={styles.container}>

     <ActivityIndicator
      animating
      color="#fff"
     size="large"
     style={styles.activityIndicator}
   />

   </View>

// Stylesheet for ActivityIndicator
const styles = StyleSheet.create ({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginTop: 70
  },
  activityIndicator: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    height: 80
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First initialize state with property `isLoading`, like as:

```
state = {
  isLoading: false
}
```

Then change its state to true when your service start.

```
this.setState({isLoading: true})
```

And set it false once you receive response from location server, either response success or failure.

```
this.setState({isLoading: false})
```

Now replace this code with yours inside render method:

```
<View style={styles.container}>
  {this.state.isLoading ? (
    <ActivityIndicator
      animating
      color="#fff"
      size="large"
      style={styles.activityIndicator}
    />
  ) : null}
</View>
```

If `this.state.isLoading` is true, Activity indicator will be displayed.

Comment: Thank for your reply and how deal this view with hitapi()

Comment: Can please update and post some code whatever there are inside hitapi() ?, So I can understand.

Comment: Please follow the link for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46148126/accessing-this-state-value-to-other-class-react-native